# How to display filebeat logs as a single file in kibana?

Tags: logstash, elk, logstash-forwarder

I have used ELK for displaying my middleware logs in kibana. for that I am using multiline patterns which mentioned below, after those logs displaying seperatly like separate expandable. How to display those logs as a single file ? as a single expandable ?
Because last couple of weeks I stucked in the same problem.

***Pattern I used:***

```
 multiline.pattern: '^\?'
 multiline.negate: true
 multiline.match: after
 multiline.max_lines: 100000
```

***Logs:***

```
04:02:22,878 DEBUG [org.jboss.modules] (main) Module org.jboss.dmr:main defined by local module loader @42f30e0a (finder: local module finder @24273305 (roots: xxxxxx))
04:02:22,885 DEBUG [org.jboss.modules] (main) Module org.jboss.as.core-security:main defined by local module loader @42f30e0a (finder: local module finder @24273305 (roots: xxxxx)
04:02:22,887 DEBUG [org.jboss.modules] (main) Module org.jboss.as.core-security-api:main defined by local module loader @42f30e0a (finder: local module finder @24273305 (roots: xxxxx))
04:02:22,894 DEBUG [org.jboss.modules] (main) Module org.jboss.as.domain-management:main defined by local module loader @42f30e0a (finder: local module finder @24273305 (roots: xxxxx))
```

Comment: You need to clarify how do you want to compile your single event and how you want your index to be.

Comment: Initially all the logs have been synced as a single expandable. After the newly created logs synced as seperatly. My guess It is the behavior of the ELK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 multiline.pattern: '^\?'
 multiline.negate: true
 multiline.match: after
 multiline.max_lines: 100000
```

The above pattern will sync all the logs as single expandable. Suppose If anything added newly then It creates as separate expandable. That is expected behaviour from  Kibana.